# Running a web server via script at startup

Tags: linux, bash

I've got a [puma](http://puma.io/) webserver running my [dashing](http://dashing.io/) dashboard from a linux VM. Currently, the VM starts as soon as my PC starts, but I have to manually run the server.

I usually do the following after ssh-ing in;

```
screen -S dashing
cd dashboard
sudo bundle exec puma
Ctrl + a + d
```

I've tried turning that into a bash script, but it doesn't seem to execute lines 2 - 4 within the screen session and I'm stuck as to how to make that work. I'm not even sure if this is the best approach to get puma running on startup (the bash script was intended to be included in `/etc/rc.local` if I could get it working).

Comment: What distro? I have a semi distro agnostic solution for this, but the best way to do this would be using the init system I suspect.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for the latest versions of ubuntu, most of them use upstart and it seems a good solution for this. I'm not familiar enough with systemd, and if your build uses it, you'd probably need a whole different version. This is why distros and versions matter.

[This](http://blog.differentpla.net/blog/2015/01/28/chromium-dashboard) seems to be a good start - and you should read through this. I'd do things a little differently and in the interests of posting a self contained answer, I've included a script as I'd write it. I'd suggest looking at both and the [upstart documentation](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/) to adjust this to fit your needs better.. I'd note you're running this as root - you really should be doing this as a specific user. I've made a few changes that make sense to me - you might want to change console log to console none if you're sure this works, and I've set explicit start and stop commands. This assumes you have a user called dashboard - you can omit the setuid and setguid commands.

Not really tested it, but it makes sense as is. Drop this into `/etc/init/dashing.conf`

```
respawn
console log
start on runlevel [23]
stop on [!23]

setuid dashboard
setgid dashboard

script
  chdir /home/dashboard/dashboard/
  dashing start
end script
```

Comment: Apologies for taking so long. This appears to have done the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Not bad. I'd note though, on the long run, you may end up needing to rewrite this for systemd. Upstart is essentially dead (and I *finally* got used to it :( )

Comment: Meh, that's a problem for future me. Thanks for the heads up though.